# How to import a mui theme color into a component?

Tags: material-ui

I want to import a Mui theme color to pass its value to a component. How can I import the color?

```
const WonderChart = () => {

  return (
    <WonderChart lineColor={theme.palette.primary.main} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useTheme` hook can be used for this.
[Documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#usetheme-theme)

```
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const WonderChart = () => {
  const theme = useTheme()
  return (
    <WonderChart lineColor={theme.palette.primary.main} />
  )
}
```